# Inverse Laplace Transform to solve second-order linear DE $[y''-2y'-99y=0, y(0)=12, y'(0)=-8]$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

I have the following second-order, linear differential equation: $y''-2y'-99y=0$ with the initial conditions $y(0)=12, y'(0)=-8$.

Converting the DE into a Laplace equation (I don't know what its actually called, professor didn't go over it), I get:

$$[s^2Y-y(0)s-y'(0)]-2[sY-y(0)]-99Y=0$$

Plugging in $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$, I get:

$$[s^2Y-12s+8]-2[sY-12]-99Y=0;$$
$$=[s^2Y-2sY-99Y]-12s+30.$$

Solving for $Y$,
$$Y[s^2-2s-99]-12s+30=0,$$
$$Y[s^2-2s-99]=12s-30,$$
$$Y=\frac{12s-30}{s^2-2s-99}.$$

$y$ is the inverse Laplace of Y ($y=L^{-1}[Y]$ ).

$$y=L^{-1}[\frac{12s-30}{s^2-2s-99}]$$
$$y=L^{-1}[\frac{61}{10(s+9)}+\frac{51}{10(s-11)}]$$

Therefore,$y=\dfrac{69}{10}e^{-9t}+\dfrac{51}{10}e^{11t}$.

However, when I enter this into my math homework program I get flagged as incorrect. Where did I make my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You have a slight addition issue, what is $$24 + 8~?$$